# make prototype of overloading function c++

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I want to make a overloading function with a prototype in C++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int rectangle(int p, int l);

int main() {
    cout << rectangle(3);
    return 0;
}

int rectangle(int p) {
    return p*p;
}

int rectangle(int p, int l) {
    return p*l;
}
```

---

I got error at

```cpp
int rectangle(int p, int l);
```

is that possible make prototype with a overloading function? if possible how to do it

Comment: Why didn't you declare the `int rectangle(int);` function like the other one?

Comment: sorry, i forget to change luasPersegi to rectangle

Comment: You're using `rectangle(int)` in `main` before it has been declared.  Either move the definition of `main` to the bottom of your program, or add a prototype for `rectangle(int)` before `main` (just like you're doing with the prototype for `rectangle(int, int)`

Comment: that what a wanna know is how to use prototype for a overloading function. i want the ```rectangle``` when i run it with one or two argument it run like overloading function like without prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to declare the function before you use/call it. You did declare the 2 argument version of `rectangle` function but you seem to forget to declare the 1 argument taking version.

As shown below if you add the declaration for the 1 argument version then your program works(compiles).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//declare the function before main
int rectangle(int p, int l);
int rectangle(int p);//ADDED THIS DECLARATION
int main() {
    cout << rectangle(3);
    return 0;
}
//define the functions after main
int rectangle(int p) {
    return p*p;
}
int rectangle(int p, int l) {
    return p*l;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Vm_BPsvOK).

**Alternative solution**:

If you don't want to declare each function separately then you should just define them before main instead of declaring them as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//define the functions before main. This way there is no need to write a separate function declaration because all definition are declarations
int rectangle(int p) {
    return p*p;
}
int rectangle(int p, int l) {
    return p*l;
}

int main() {
    cout << rectangle(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "You've to declare the function before you use/call it." - alternatively, just define the function before it's used without a separate declaration. For single-file programs, forward-declaration is only needed when there's a mutual dependency.

Comment: so I need the same number of prototypes as overloading function?

Comment: @HanifRamadhani or put all your functions before main. Use forward declaration unless you really need it.

Comment: @HanifRamadhani If you don't want to declare each function separately, then you can just define them before main as i have done in my **alternative solution**. Check out the *alternative solution* that i have added in my answer.

Comment: I would even reverse order of overload and call `rectangle(p, p)` from `rectangle(int p)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes that is possible but i wonder if that's a good idea in this case. In this simple case there is no need to call another function because we can just get the result by directly writing `return p*p` instead of increasing the call overhead by calling another function.

Comment: It removes the "duplication" logic. Chance are the code would be inlined by compiler anyway.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes there is possibility of inlining by the compiler but i think when teaching anything to a beginner it is important to not add unnecessary things. When they get comfortable enough with the language then we should say that you could do this. This(the above statement) is just my opinion or the way i teach C++ to beginners. You may have other opinion. Or if telling them an alternative i try to tell about the consequences of the alternative and what the compiler can/can't do.